# Ternary Operators and Eval in C# .Net - Cannot convert string to bool

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project that has data that may or may not have files associated with it. If the record does not have a file associated with it, I do not want to display the link/label. I thought this would be fairly simple to implement with the ternary operator, but I receive the following:

```
: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'
```

resulting from the line containing this statement

```
<asp:Label Visible='<%#  Eval("supportingDocuments") == null ? "False" : "True" %>' id="supportingFileLink" runat="server" Text='Other' />
```

To me, this implies that it is seeing  `Eval("supportingDocuments") == null` as a string and not a conditional that can be evaluated as a boolean. I have tried adding parentheses around the condition, but this did not change anything.

EDIT: This is an a databound GridView control; sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: "False" and "True" are strings, not booleans.

Comment: I know "True" and "False" are technically strings, but whenever manually defining the visible property in a ASP.NET web control, it has the form  Visible="false" , so I am just curious why my approach did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It must not be liking the double quotes around `"True"` and `"False"`.

You could try:

```
Visible='<%#  Eval("supportingDocuments") == null ? false : true %>'
```

Or better still, you can probably simplify to:

```
Visible='<%#  Eval("supportingDocuments") != null %>'
```

Comment: I love a simple, elegant fix. Thanks so much!